# Can't use injected value as constructor of another injection

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I would like to define 2 injected classes, but one needs to use the second class method for the constructor. I am using Koin framework

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val connectionService : ConnectionService by inject()

    private val resourcesHelper : ResourcesHelper by inject()

    private val addressPropertyName = "connection.address"
    private val portPropertyName = "connection.port"

    private val appModule = module {
        single { ResourcesHelperImpl(androidContext(), R.raw.config) }
        single {
            ConnectionServiceTcp(
             resourcesHelper.getConfigValueAsString(addressPropertyName),
                resourcesHelper.getConfigValueAsInt(portPropertyName)
            )
        }
    }
```

And then I get an error because I cannot instantiate ConnectionServiceTcp using resourcesHelper. Is there a way to use injected field to inject another field?

Edit
Changing to get() helped, but now I struggle with module configuration.
I moved start koin to MainApplication class:

```
class MainApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@MainApplication)
            androidLogger()
            modules(appModule)
        }
    }
}
```

And module to AppModule.kt

```
val appModule = module {
    single { ResourcesHelperImpl(androidContext(), R.raw.drone) }
    single {
        ConnectionServiceTcp(
            get<ResourcesHelper>().getConfigValueAsString(ResourcesHelper.droneAddressPropertyName),
            get<ResourcesHelper>().getConfigValueAsInt(ResourcesHelper.dronePortPropertyName)
        )
    }
    scope(named<MainActivity>()) {
        scoped {
            ConnectionServiceTcp(get(), get())
        }
    }

}
```

And then I try to inject some object to activities and I am getting
Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for has been found. Check your module definitions.

Comment: Have you try this `single {ConnectionServiceTcp(get<ResourcesHelper>().getConfigValueAsString(addressPropertyName)...}` ? Also, I think you should move the module to separated file, and `startKoin` in `Application` class.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I encountered two problems, firstly I could not instantiate bean using other bean in constructor, it was resolved by changing my invoke to

```
        ConnectionServiceTcp(
            get<ResourcesHelper>().getConfigValueAsString(ResourcesHelper.droneAddressPropertyName),
            get<ResourcesHelper>().getConfigValueAsInt(ResourcesHelper.dronePortPropertyName)
        )
```

Secondly, there was a problem with NoBeanDefFoundException, it was due `androidContext()` in ResourcesHelperImpl, I needed there Context from the activity, not the koin context.